# calling oncreate within constructor

Tags: android

I am calling a class's member function from another class. So,I am creating an object of the class for which i have to call constructor. Within that constructor, I need to call onc reate method of my activity class.how can I do it?

Comment: Do u mean to say that the class and ur activity are same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,i presume u r trying to call a constructor in an activity.If that is the case then some thing is wrong in the way u have designed ur project.For more details check out these links
[Creating an object of Android Activity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215875/creating-an-object-of-activity-class) and [Android - Activity Constructor vs onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302177/android-activity-constructor-vs-oncreate)

Answer (score 5):

Do not call onCreate from your constructor.  The system itself will call onCreate for you.

Take a look at the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) for more information of how onCreate is called.

Answer (score 0):

All  method's of Activity class should be called within activity only . write your own methods for whatever operation you need to perform  and pass data from other Activity/class by various data transfer algorithms .

Comment: Thanks for the info. But, still i am getting error in my constructor.                                                  public myactivity(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Log.v("myactivity", "Inside myactivity Constructor");
db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
if (db == null)
Log.v("myactivity", "DB Creation Failed");
 }                                                                    Can u please help me?

Comment: nobody can . until you post code with errorLog . so please do it

Comment: Thanks Shailndra, finally got it. Created anew project & implemented on create method instead of going for constructor.